# Step Function Invoke SSM document that takes Volume ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I'm encountering an issue with a step function definition in AWS. One of the state definitions looks like this:

```
{
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:ssm:startAutomationExecution.waitForTaskToken",
  "Parameters": {
    "DocumentName.$": "$.lambdaOutput.DocumentName",
    "TargetParameterName": "$.lambdaOutput.volume_id",
    "Targets": [
      {
        "Key": "ParameterValues",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Key": "volumeId",
            "Values": "$.lambdaOutput.volume_id"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "Next": "DecideNextStep"
}
```

and im receiving the error

```
Missing required parameter: volumeId in user inputs. (Service: Ssm, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 69cc4aaf-e962-4d6a-a4b7-7b8612630fa4)
```

I've reviewed the AWS documentation but couldn't find a solution. Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!